# What is the correct parameter range to choose when conducting a sensitivity analysis?

Tags: statistical-significance, variance, interaction, uncertainty, sensitivity-analysis

When conducting a (variance-based) sensitivity analysis, should I set the range of a specific parameter to its maximum allowable range, or restrict it to something more appropriate for my specific case study?

For example, If I want to conduct a (variance-based) sensitivity analysis to determine if model x is sensitive to parameter A, where A's physical range is defined as [0, 1], should the sensitivity analysis be carried out for the whole range -- that is [0, 1] -- or for a subset of it that is bounded by the uncertainty of my observation for my specific case study -- perhaps 0.8 +- 0.1?

In a way, these are quite different assumptions and the latter seems more like an uncertainty analysis...

Comment: Great question! "Who analyzes the sensitivity of the sensitivity analyzer"? (Can anyone write that in latin :)). In my view, the only way to proceed is to try it several different ways, i.e. in your example both for [0,1] and for [0.8,0.9]. You will get different results, and learn not only from the individual results, but from the difference between them, about the sensitivity of your problem.

Answer (score 0):

The parameter range (as well as the parameter uncertainty distribution), set by the study maker, is mostly dependent on what you want to measure.

Here, you are saying that the uncertainty of one of the uncertain parameters of your model will not range its whole physical range. Then, in you sensitivty analysis, you should test for the uncertainty you know it can have (0.8 +- 0.1 according to your question).

Comment: If the sensitivity analysis (SA) explores the same parameter space that is going to be explored by the uncertainty analysis UA, SA == UA?

Comment: UA is about computing the output distribution (at least confidence intervals); SA is more about knowing where this uncertainty come from (i.e. how much each uncertain input parameter contributes to it)